# Recuperar un valor que envía un html a un servlet para después usarlo en una clase conexión

Tags: java, servlets

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><h1 class="Titulo"><font color=orange>Seleccione Base de Datos</font></h1>
        <div class="container">
            <form class="form__reg" action="Selecciona" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr><td width="150" align=center>
                            <label>MySQL</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input" type="radio" id="base" name="base" value=1>
                        </td></tr>

                    <tr><td>
                            <label>SQL Server</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input" type="radio" id="base" name="base" value=2>
                        </td></tr>

                    <tr><td>
                            <label>PostgreSQL</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input" type="radio" id="base" name="base" value=3>
                        </td></tr>
                </table>
                <div class="btn__form">
                    <input class="btn__submit" type="submit" value="ACEPTAR">               
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

El servlet que recibe el value 1, 2 o 3:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet Selecciona</title>");
        out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/cajasred.css'/>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<br>");
      int tb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("base"));
        switch (tb) {
            case 1:
                out.println("<form class='form__reg' action='Login.jsp'>");
                out.println("<div class='box-blue'>");
                out.println("<center><input class='btn__submit' type='submit' style='font-size: 15pt;' value='INGRESAR AL SISTEMA MySQL'></center>");
                out.println("</div>");
                out.println("</form>");
                break;
            case 2:
                out.println("<form class='form__reg' action='Login.jsp'>");
                out.println("<div class='box-green'>");
                out.println("<center><input class='btn__submit' type='submit' style='font-size: 15pt;' value='INGRESAR AL SISTEMA SQL Server'></center>");
                out.println("</div>");
                out.println("</form>");
                break;
            default:
                out.println("<center><h2>EN MANTENIMIENTO</h2>");
                out.println("<a href='index.html'><font color = red style='font-size:25px'>Vuelva a Ingresar</font></a><br>");
                out.println("<img src='IMG/construccion.jpg' alt=''/></center>");
                break;
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

El value  del html quiero usarlo en una clase conexion

```
package conexion;
import cadena.ClaseCadena;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.*;
public class Conexion extends Selecciona {

    ClaseCadena cad = new ClaseCadena();
    public Connection cn = null;
    public Connection conexionBd() {
        try {
            switch (tipoBase) {
                case 1:
                    cad.setCadConDri("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    cad.setCadConbd("jdbc:mysql://localhost/agenciabus");
                    cad.setUsuario("root");
                    cad.setPass("1234");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cad.setCadConDri("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    cad.setCadConbd("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=agenciabus");
                    cad.setUsuario("sa");
                    cad.setPass("123456");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            Class.forName(cad.getCadConDri());
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(cad.getCadConbd(), cad.getUsuario(), cad.getPass());
        } catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("NO se conecto \n" + e);
        }
        return cn;
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Mirá quería ver si podía organizarte este código desde mi IDE pero hay clases que no colocaste como ClaseCadena y Selecciona, pero bueno, veo de hacer algo similar a lo que querés hacer pero sin esas clases. Para la respuesta que vos pedís no es necesario una respuesta muy larga, se ve que quizás tu consulta específica sería como enviar el dato hasta el backend o controller, la respuesta es bastante simple, javascript ajax es una posibilidad. igualmente veo si puedo hacer un esquema un poco distinto pero que te ayude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno en principio entiendo que lo que no te funciona es el "***value***" de los **input** que vienen desde el *Front-end* al *Back-end*, como *opinión* antes de entrar a la respuesta te digo: ví que tenés un Servlet que se llama processRequest(HttpServlet request, etc), no está mal, sin embargo como *recomendación* podría decirte que **si usás servlet**, **sólo** te muevas entre los dos métodos predefinidos, **doGet()** y **doPost()**, la razón es que la mayoría de las ***llamadas se realizan por javascript***, el cual tiene *predefinido dos métodos universales get y post*, los cuales cuando los definís dentro de un servlet **impactan directamente en doGet() y doPost** respectivamente. También fijate que en el form html hay un atributo que llama "**method**", el mismo recibe **get** y **post**, evitando tener que definir el mismo dentro de la llamada javascript.

**Ahora a la respuesta específica:**

Empiezo con un pantallazo de la estructura sobre la cual armé el ejemplo, que quizás te pueda servir a vos para pulir algunas cuestiones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Empezamos desde el archivo HTML/JSP, en mi caso utilicé un jsp porque estoy muy habituado nomás, sin embargo si usás html podés prescindir del código de arriba, en el mismo está la misma estructura que presentaste vos con unos ligeros cambios de orden y el **añadido de una función javascript** sin framework, que **realiza una llamada al backend enviando los datos del formulario declarado**, te invito a que léas lo comentado en el código para mejor guía.

*El siguiente archivo es el principal en el envío de datos.*

**index.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <!-- LLamada javascript ajax simple sin framework para envío de datos al Servlet -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendValue() {
            /* Damos variables a los elementos HTML que vamos a utilizar, al formulario que luego va a ser enviados los values */
            var frm = document.frmSendValues;
            var inputValue = document.frmSendValues.base;

            /* Los números los podés poner entre comillas o no, javascript es indiferente en ése tema */
            if (inputValue.val() == 1) {
                inputValue = 1;
            } else {
                inputValue = 2;
            }
            frm.submit();
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="SendValuesServlet" method="get" name="frmSendValues">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>SQL Server</label></td>
                        <td><input class="input" type="radio" id="base" name="base"
                            value=1></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label>PostgreSQL</label></td>
                        <td><input class="input" type="radio" id="base" name="base"
                            value=2></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="btnForm">
                    <input class="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="ACEPTAR">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Ahora el **Servlet**, como verás es distinto a lo que publicaste vos porque **sólo quiero demostrar si funciona el switch**, declarando **dos conexiones distintas a DB**, la primera la tengo activa y abierta, la segunda sólo tengo el conector agregado al build-path pero no la tengo levantada, así que en el swicth para que no salte una excepción le indiqué que si entra al segundo switch salgo un System.out y que a su vez le de un valor nulo a la conexión, sino me iba a tirar muchas excepciones que no van al caso.

**SendValuesServlet**

```
    package com.soa.servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import com.soa.controllers.ClientController;

    public class SendValuesServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            String value = request.getParameter("base");
            /* Los datos de los parámetros están harcodeados para el ejemplo nomás, en su momento harás un getParameter() o harás lo que quieras, pero el value tiene que estar seguro para que el dato entre en el switch */
            ClientController.exampleInsertQuery("unDato", "otroDato", value);

            response.getWriter().write("El Servlet es llamado con normalidad");
        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            doGet(request, response);
        }

    }
```

Sólo a modo de prueba íntegra para ver si funcionaba bien realicé una tabla llamada **clients**, donde insertar datos **y persistirlos en mysql**, y como te repito **cuando se seleccionaba el segundo input la conexión es "null"** porque así la declaré **para que no salte excepción**.

Fijate que **en la declaración de parámetros le agregué un input más**, un **String** en este caso, pero porqué declaro un String si el value que va a recibir del Front end va a ser un entero?

Porque el **método** que voy a usar **sólo dentro del Servlet** es el **request.getParameter("nombreDeInputHtml")** que **siempre toma los datos con forma de String** y como no tengo ganas de parsear los datos a **Integer** lo dejo así, como si fuera un String, se puede trabajar tranquilamente.

**ClientController**

```
    package com.soa.controllers;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import com.soa.dao.ConnectionStackOverflow;

    public class ClientController {

        /* Método para insertar a la DB, le agregamos por parámetro un String que va a ser el value del HTML/JSP */
        public static void exampleInsertQuery(String name, String lastname, String value) {
            Connection connection = null;
            /* Intentamos conectarnos, le ponemos el parámetro al método conexión para que internamente prosece el switch */
            try {
                connection = ConnectionStackOverflow.getConexion(value);

                /* Si no es nula que entre al método que nos facilita realizar la insercción */
                if (connection != null) {
                    PreparedStatement ps;
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO clients(name, lastname) VALUES(?,?)";
                    ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps.setString(1, name);
                    ps.setString(2, lastname);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    ps.close();
                    System.out.println("Query executed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection appears to be null");
                }
            } catch (Exception error) {
                System.out.println("Cannot even connect");
                error.getMessage();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Para que los Servlet funcionen bien (se puede usar anotaciones pero no es este ejemplo), **hay que declararlos en un archivo** aparte que habitualmente se coloca dentro de la carpeta **WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml**, la configuración específica de este ejemplo es la siguiente:

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>StackOverflowWeb</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <!-- SendValuesServlet -->
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SendValuesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.soa.servlets.SendValuesServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SendValuesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SendValuesServlet</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Si por alguna razón te tira error **en la primer linea** del archivo **web.xml**, fijate de borrarla y ver si funciona.

**ConnectionStackOverflow** (Archivo devuelve Connection)

En esta clase están definidas las dos conexiones dentro de un switch, dependiendo el value que llegue desde el front end va a conectarse a una u otra.

```
    package com.soa.dao;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class ConnectionStackOverflow {

        private final static String user = "root";
        private final static String password = "";
        static Connection connection = null;

        public static Connection getConexion(String value)
                throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {

            /*
             * Porqué utilizo los números como si fueran String? porque voy a traer los
             * datos por Servlet por getParameter() que sólo acepta String, y como no tengo
             * ganas de parsear lo simplifico y listo
             */
            switch (value) {
            case "1":
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agenciabus", user, password);
                System.out.println("Entró en el primer switch");
                break;

            case "2":
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                // connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=agenciabus" , user, password);
                System.out.println("Entró en el segundo switch");
                connection = null;
                break;
            }
            return connection;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Tomar en cuenta que no tengo levantada una base de datos microsoft para hacer
     * las pruebas, sólo dejo como funciona el swicth andando bien, si seleccionamos
     * el input radio 1 entra al Mysql, y si seleccionamos el 2 entra al microsoft
     * que lo tengo comentado y a su vez le asigné un null para que no me tire
     * ninguna excepción, porque entiendasé que el método declarado como
     * "Connection" tiene que devolver sí o sí un connection o un null, así que como
     * no tengo un DB activa de ése tipo preferí ponerle "null", entiéndase también
     * que tiene que haber una tabla con el mismo nombre que el método definido en
     * ClientController y con la misma cantidad de columnas y nombre, a menos que de
     * alguna manera en el mismo método del controller se haga otro switch que
     * inserte en otra tabla u otra cosa.
     */
```

Por si te interesa replicarlo te dejo la estructura de la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ahora probamos si funciona:**
Seleccionamos el primer radio le damos aceptar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Checkeamos la DB:**
Para ver si el **switch** entró en la **conexión** correspondiente **MySql**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ahora probamos el segundo input**, el que **iría técnicamente** a la **DB** de **microsoft**, que "no la tengo levantada" pero el switch funciona:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Para terminar, unas cosas a tener en cuenta:**

• Las llamadas o envío de datos, pueden ser hechas de diversas formas, por javascript sin framework, por algun framework javascript como JQuery el más habitual, por el form html directamente, etc.

• Tenés que tener un Servlet que esté escuchando los "request", y que a su vez correspondan a un doGet() o doPost(), dentro de los mismos hacés lo que querés pero siempre intentando separar por capas así ponés la mínima cantidad de código posible dentro del servlet. (En este caso usé un método de insercción que está en otra clase).

• El Servlet hay que declararlo en el archivo web.xml (si no se usan anotaciones).

• Los Servlet no pueden duplicarse

**Intenté dejarte una respuesta de buena calidad, con algo hecho de principio a fin y relativamente bien organizado.**

***Espero que le sirva a cualquiera que necesite algo similar.***

Comment: Hola @julio-alvarado te dejé una respuesta amplia, quizás te sirva. Abrazos.

Comment: Gracias lo revisare a fondo

Comment: Ok, si te sirve y sólo si soluciona tu duda, marcala como pregunta respondida.

Comment: Si pudieras compartir el código del paquete com.soa.dao

Comment: La clase ConnectionStackverflow. java

Comment: Ahí está, se me había pasado ésa clase.

Comment: Te lo agradezco infinitamente era lo que necesitaba

Comment: @julio-alvarado, buenísimo que te haya servido, si podés cerrá la pregunta marcándola como solucionada, abrazos!!!